# Speed of spontaneous mixing of different gases

Tags: statistical-mechanics, diffusion

Suppose we have a rectangular box divided into two equal cubic parts by a vertical impenetrable wall. Part 1 of the box contains a standard state mixture of $(1-x)$ mole of  gas $A$ (e.g. Oxygen) and $x$ mole of gas $B$ (e.g. Carbon dioxide), while part 2 contains 1 mole  of standard state gas $A$. Let the wall suddenly disappear without causing any disturbance of the gases. After infinite time there will be $\frac{x}{2}$ mole of gas $B$ in both parts. The question: how could we calculate or estimate the time needed for being $0.51\,x$ mole in part 1 and $0.49\,x$ mole in part 2?

**Edit**: Suppose we know every physical properties of $A$ and $B$, or if it's easier, take them definitely to Oxygen and Carbon dioxide.

Comment: How do you suppose to do this without knowing the rate of diffusion of $B$ in $A$?

Comment: I don't suppose anything. If we need the rate of diffusion of $B$ in $A$, then let's use it.

Comment: It is a material property. You do not specify it in your question so either you don't know its value or you are supposed to estimate it. Usage of the tag 'statistical-mechanics' leads me to believe your are supposed to estimate it using a [result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion#The_theory_of_diffusion_in_gases_based_on_Boltzmann.27s_equation) from SM? Otherwise, i would simply take a value of $D \sim 10^{-6} \mathrm{m^2/s}$  representative for diffusion in gases.

Comment: OK, let's take $D \sim 10^{-6} \mathrm{m^2/s}$. What's next?

Comment: Set up a species balance for the rate of change in concentration of $A$ or $B$ which equals the species flux from one compartment to another. This flux will be dependent on the concentration difference and a mass transfer coefficient equal to $D/L$ where $L$ is the characteristic length scale of the problem, in this case the size of a compartment. The concentration difference will dependent on the concentration in both concentrations which change in time but can be simplified by using the fact that the total mass of $A$ or $B$ doesn't change. Then integrate and find the time for your problem..

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer:** just so you know the following analysis assumes the compartments are well-mixed (diffusion is fast) which is likely a poor assumption, but it makes the analysis doable within engineering accuracy.

So first off lets confirm that indeed the steady-state concentration of $B$ is what you say it is. Since there is no reaction between $A$ and $B$, we can use a total mole balance over the two compartments:
$$n_{b,1} + n_{b,2} = n_{b,0}$$
while not specifically stated in the question, i've assumed the volumes of the compartments are the same $V_1=V_2=V$.

At steady-state there will be no gradients in the system and the number of moles in compartment 1 and 2 will be equal $n_{b,1}^{ss}=n_{b,2}^{ss}=n_{b,f}$ which indeed leads to $n_{b,f}=n_{b,0}/2$.

Now to find the number of moles of $B$ in compartment 1 as a function of time, we set up a transport equation relating the rate of change of $B$ to the flux of $B$ out of compartment 1:
$$\frac{dn_{b,1}}{dt}=-ka\left(n_{b,1}-n_{b,2}\right)$$
where $ka=\frac{D}{L}\frac{A}{V}=\frac{D}{L^2}$ is a mass transfer coefficient (in this case the inverse of the characteristic time for diffusion), $D$ the diffusion coefficient and $L$ the characteristic length scale for diffusion (size of compartment). $n_{b,1}$ and $n_{b,2}$ are functions of time making this by itself difficult to solve, however by substituting the total mole balance we get:
$$\frac{dn_{b,1}}{dt}=-ka\left(2n_{b,1}-n_{b,0}\right)$$
which has a simple solution of the form:
$$\frac{n_{B,1}}{n_{B,0}}=\frac{1}{2}\left[1+\exp\left(-2kat\right)\right]
 $$
which shows the concentration in compartment 1 follows an exponential decay in time with time constant $\frac{1}{2ka}$. As $t\rightarrow\infty$ we find the same steady-state result previously found.

Rearranging the equation for the time to reach a specific concentration yields:
$$t=-\frac{1}{ka}\ln\left(2\frac{n_{b,1}}{n_{b,0}}-1\right)
 $$

Substituting some values for $n_{b,0}=x$ and $n_{b,1}=0.51x$ yields:
$$t=\frac{1}{2ka}\ln 50 \approx 2\frac{L^2}{D}$$
Determining appropriate values for $ka$ or $\frac{L^2}{D}$ will yield a time. On average, after two diffusion time scales it has reached your desired concentration.

Comment: Thanks! This is clearly a lower bound for the "mixing time" $t$. Could you also provide an upper bound?

Comment: @mma - yes, clearly because of the assumption of 'well-mixedness' this is an lower bound. It is difficult to say what is the approximate upper bound without stating the obvious ($t\rightarrow\infty$); i would conservatively say $t\approx10\frac{L^2}{D}$. Since the characteristic time for diffusion is $\frac{L^2}{D}$, an order of magnitude longer should be sufficient to effectively make all gradients vanish.

Comment: @mma - I fixed a mistake I made in rearranging for the time. Also for $t\approx10\frac{L^2}{D}$ it follows $\frac{n_{b,1}}{n_{b,0}}\approx\frac{1}{2}$ so we have practically reached a steady state.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your transport equation and your result. Taking from [Feynman's](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_43.html) (43.22) 
$$\frac{dn_{b,1}}{dt}=-A\frac{v}{V}\left(n_{b,1}-n_{b,2}\right)= \frac{dn_{b,1}}{dt}=-\frac{v}{L}\left(n_{b,1}-n_{b,2}\right)$$, and from (43.27)  $v=\frac{3D}{l}$ , your $ka=\frac{3D}{lL}$, where $l$ is the mean free path, so it is independent of $L$. So, your result gives in fact a linear dependence of the mixing time on $L$ rather than quadratic. Am I right?

Comment: @mma - well i wouldn't want to argue with feynman :) I suppose you could argue that the mean free path is a better length scale for diffusion than the size of the compartment. However, I would stress that $k$ is really an engineering quantity which should be determined from experiments. Anything else is guessing at its value and may introduce errors in the calculations. Remember all of this is within 'engineering accuracy' meaning that this answer is accurate within an order of magnitude.

Comment: Could you tell me what is this $k$ and what is $a$? And where the relationship between $k$, $D$, and $L$ comes from?

Comment: @mma - on the other hand, I would say that the mean free path is better length scale for short times where the molecules have diffused a distance on the order of the mean free path. For long times, in which you are interested since you are near equilibrium, the molecules will have diffused several orders of magnitudes of the mean free path and then I would argue that the size of the compartment is the characteristic lenght scale.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31351/discussion-between-nluigi-and-mma).